# Evaluating a lambda function with if else f'y{x}' inside the sorted method

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have the following sorting problem:

Given a list of strings, return the list of strings
sorted, but group all strings starting with 'x' first.

Example: ['mix', 'banana' ,'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
Will return: ['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'banana' ,'mix']

I solved by splitting the list into 2:

```
def front_x(words):

    return [w for w in words if w[0] == "x"] + [w for w in words if w[0] != "x"]
```

Another pythonic solution for this problem would be using `sorted` method, like this:

```
def front_x(words):

    return sorted(words, key=lambda x: x if x[0] == 'x' else f'y{x}')
```

I am having a hard time to understand what is going on after `else`. Any good soul to help me out? I'm grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
return sorted(words, key=lambda x: x if x[0] == 'x' else f'y{x}')
```

Translation:

"Return a sorted version of `words`. For each item `x` in `words`, use `x` for comparison when sorting, but only if `x[0]` is equal to the character `'x'`. Otherwise, append `'y'` to the front of `x` and use that for comparison instead"

The `f'y{x}'` syntax is the [f-string syntax](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). It's equivalent to:

```py
"y" + str(x)
```

There are plenty of other equivalent ways to insert a character into a string. That's just how it's being done here.

So, if your word list was:

```
aardvark
xylophone
xamarin
xenophobia
zipper
apple
bagel
yams
```

The list would be sorted as if it contained the following:

```
yaardvark
xylophone
xamarin
xenophobia
yzipper
yapple
ybagel
yyams
```

And therefore the output would be:

```
xamarin
xenophobia
xylophone
aardvark
apple
bagel
yams
zipper
```

So, what is happening is that, when the list is sorted, items that start with `'x'` will always appear before any other items.

Answer (score 1):

`f'y{x}'` in an [f-string expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) that prepends the character `'y'` to the original string (`x`).  That way, all items that don't start with `'x'` will sort *as if* they started with `'y'`, which puts them after all of the items that *do* start with `'x'`.

For example, `'banana'` will be sorted *as if* it was `'ybanana'`, which naturally places it after `'xyz'`.